# Facebook using iOS integration, broken for two days

Tags: ios, facebook

I work on an iOS app which can post to Facebook. Everything worked fine until a few days ago when Facebook was down for half an hour. Ever since then I have been receiving a constant stream of emails from users saying they cannot post to Facebook. I had a look at the code and found an issue which has now been corrected which I thought may be the cause of the problem.

While waiting for the update I have advised users to force quit the app since this should fix the bug in question, however they are reporting back that this does not fix the problem.

I just logged into Facebook to view my app there and according to Facebook there has not been a single request made in four days. Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

My app uses iOS's Facebook integration for accounts and I have just tested my app and it works fine for me. I cannot understand how this could suddenly just stop working for a whole bunch of people despite no changes to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook made a huge change in their api a few days ago. Actually on Thursday, so this is probably the cause of your troubles.

All apps have been switched over to version 2.0 of the api and many privileges that were automatic now have to be explicitly granted by Facebook  after submitting the app for review.

Posting on behalf of a user is one of the permissions that now must be explicitly granted to an app.

Have you logged into the developers page for your app? If there are issues you'll see notifications there.

Comment: I don't seem to have any notifications but it appears you are correct. Thanks.